# Using php variable in tex equation

Tags: php, latex, tex

I have an equation that gets rendered by mathjax and I have a result that is calculated via php into a php variable.

How can I combine the two (to be rendered as tex and not two different parts)?

The equation:

```
\(\frac{\sum Mark*CountedMarks}{\sum validMarks}=\)
```

and my php variable `$result`

I tried so far:

```
\(\frac{\sum Mark*CountedMarks}{\sum validMarks}=$result\)
```

which does not work.

This would **not** be a solution that fits my needs because $result is not rendered:

```
".'\(\frac{\sum Mark*CountedMarks}{\sum validMarks}=\)'." $result
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to put result under the bracket: `'\(\frac{\sum Mark*CountedMarks}{\sum validMarks}='.$result.'\)'`

Comment: oh wow. sometimes I am dumb. Thanks for the obvious and easy solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Fresh eye sometimes is the best debugging tool.

Comment: @mudasobwa You should add this as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put result under the bracket:

```
'\(\frac{\sum Mark*CountedMarks}{\sum validMarks}='.$result.'\)'
```

Hope it helps.